# Checking armstrong number in python 3 using for loop instead of while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to write a code for checking armstrong number in python 3 using for loop instead of while loop?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Start by defining what is an armstrong number, and show your code where you did it using while loop

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
# Python Program For Armstrong Number using For Loop

number = int(input("\nPlease Enter the Number to Check for Armstrong: "))

# Initializing Sum and Number of Digits
sum = 0
times = 0

# Calculating Number of individual digits
temp = number
while temp > 0:
    times = times + 1
    temp = temp // 10

# Finding Armstrong Number
temp = number
for n in range(1, temp + 1):
    reminder = temp % 10
    sum = sum + (reminder ** times)
    temp //= 10

if number == sum:
    print("\n %d is Armstrong Number.\n" %number)
else:
    print("\n %d is Not a Armstrong Number.\n" %number)
```

Comment: Please respect the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Here it's about variable names in lower case and an indentation with 4 spaces.

Comment: @Matthias thanks for pointing out! corrected for now.